# Passing in an async function into the closure that returns a Result<T> which rayon::IntoParallelIterator.map accepts

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, rayon

I have these async functions, `add_two_num`, `check_num`:

```
use anyhow::{Error, Result, Ok};
use rayon::prelude::*;

pub async fn add_two_num(num_one: u64, num_two: u64) -> Result<u64> {
    check_num(num_one).await?; // calls another async function that returns a anyhow::Result<T>, where `T` is a different `T` from the return of the `add_two_num` function
    check_num(num_two).await?;
    anyhow::Ok(num_one + num_two)
}

pub async fn check_num(num: u64) -> Result<()> {
    assert!(num <= u64::MAX);
    Ok(())
}
```

These functions are just contrived functions, the point is to make the return type `anyhow::Result<T>` where `T` is different at different call sites in `add_two_num`, e.g. `check_sum` called twice, each returning `anyhow::Result<()>` (`T`=`()`).

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let nums_one: Vec<u64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    let nums_two: Vec<u64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    let results = nums_one.into_par_iter()
    .zip_eq(nums_two.into_par_iter())
    .map(async move |(num_one, num_two)| {
        add_two_num(num_one, num_two).await?
        // questions: 1. how to write this closure to be passed into `.map()`?
        // 2. the `?` operator will early return the error, how to indicate this into the signature of the closure or basically, how to 'iterate' over the Result<T>?
    }).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    Ok(())
}
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

1. Zip both IntoParallelIterator, send them into a closure.
2. The closure calls async functions within the closure, the async functions uses the `?` operator to return early the `anyhow::Error`.

Questions:

1. How to write the closure to call async functions within the closure?
2. How to write the signature of the closure to indicate that it returns a `anyhow::Result<T>`?

Comment: Hi @user4815162342, thank you for your answer, yes it definitely did help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily call async functions from Rayon's callbacks. But since you're already using async, you could avoid Rayon altogether, and spawn async tasks (which do run in parallel) for your operations:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let nums_one: Vec<u64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    let nums_two: Vec<u64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    let tasks = nums_one
        .into_iter()
        .zip_eq(nums_two)
        .map(|(num_one, num_two)| {
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                let result = add_two_num(num_one, num_two).await?;
                Ok::<_, anyhow::Error>(result)
            })
        })
        .collect_vec();
    let v: Vec<u64> = future::join_all(tasks)
        .await
        .into_iter()
        // this unwrap triggers only in case of panic
        .map(|result| result.unwrap())
        .collect::<Result<_, _>>()?;
    assert_eq!(v, [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]);
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=056cd5d25cdb335b32a6ca8828e4ef44)

Comment: (1) You don't need to `collect()` the futures, `join_all()` accepts iterators. (2) You can `unwrap()` near the `spawn()` call. (3) You can use `try_join_all()`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba008d7e1a09cff6e34531c1448d97ce

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks for (1) and (3), but (2) is actually a mistake. By awaiting the handle immediately, you've effectively serialized the async code inside, and thus undone the purpose of calling `tokio::spawn()` in the first place. Equivalent mistake in threading is overzealously refactoring `let results = iter.map(|x| spawn(calculate)).collect::<Vec<_>>().map(|handle| handle.join().unwrap())` by omitting the "unnecessary" collect (which was even erroneously [suggested by clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/8055)!). The result is slower code that still appears to work.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman After thinking about this some more, I see that my analysis is mistaken. Yes, the `spawn()` is immediately followed by an `.await`, but the whole thing is in its own `async` block, and `join_all()` should run those concurrently. [This playground example[(https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab2d96f73bc3f3ba1d998ee79ae4faab) shows the example I was referring to, as well as one equivalent to yours. "Apologies for the confusion", as a popular AI would say.

Comment: However, I feel that the code in my answer is still clearer and easier to reason about. The unwrap to be "away" from the spawn is in a sense correct, because it communicates that the unwrap should happen at join time, not at spawn time.