# Using Rayon with SQLX "iterator-like" stream of rows

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx, rayon

Rust SQLX lib provides an iterator-like interface `fetch(...)` usually used with `while let Some(row) = rows.try_next().await? {...}` construct.  In my case, each row may take some time to process, so I would like to use Rayon's `par_iter()`, but that requires a real iterator. Using `fetch_all` is not an option because all rows may simply not fit into memory.

How can I use Rayon's `par_iter` to process millions of rows produced by the sqlx's `fetch` stream?

Comment: That's called a [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) (specifically a `TryStream`) and could be done by [`spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html), sending everything through a channel to a thread running Rayon, or simply [`buffer_unordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffer_unordered) depending on what's happening in the while loop.

Comment: Since you use async already, you don't necessarily need rayon to introduce parallelism. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76099638/1600898) for an example.